# Among the Worlds top language that I am, Would be the one that serves, Ultimately the n00bs!

Tags: riddle, computer-puzzle

Among the World's top language that I am,
Would be the one that serves,
Ultimately the n00bs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take the statement quite literally I would suggest the answer is

> a programming language, something along the lines of BASIC, because it serves beginners to learn.

Comment: Yes you got it right : ). The riddle was on a ctf website. Found out that the answer was hidden in the source code. Though it was in leet code 6@$!c.